# What is "Ask Patents" and why is it secret?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-sites, design, ask-patents

Looks like our SE overlords are about to launch a new Stack Exchange site - [Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com). I've been hinted at its existence by a user who committed to the (now closed) Software Law proposal on Area 51.

> [image]

Did I miss the memo or something? There's no site entry in Area51, and doubly suspicious is that it already has its own theme.

Sorry if some beans were spilled, but I'm curious why was it kept under wraps.

Comment: Not that secret [if you look at the Meta-User list](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/users).

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby: It's "secret" if you can't find it on Area51, and it's not advertised anywhere else on the SE network. And more than 50% of the users are SE staff or affiliated.

Comment: Some secrets are meant to be secret.

Comment: Who will be the lucky new owner of SE? Google or the healthy red fruit?

Comment: Well, most likely because they want to try it in a controlled environment. This pretty much scratches the area of "legal advice" which is a touchy subject and has the potential to blow into someones face. Despite the discussion I once led with Won't, I now agree that giving legal advice on a website is a problem which needs to be handled carefully.

Comment: I think it's better to remove the link to area 51 from its footer as it was not launched by the community.

Comment: I think every committer to Software Law got an invite.

Comment: They also have a chatroom, so it's still not that secret

Comment: I am active in the private beta, and believe me when I say this .. you will be _very_ glad this site exists when it launches. I proposed a "Software patent busters" site to crowd source prior art a long time ago that fizzled out, which is why I was invited to the private beta. If this kicks, and it looks like it will, we're all going to benefit.

Comment: It's not secret. It's just patented.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's...a site about patents!  It'll be in private beta for ~2 weeks, and then you'll hear a lot more about it.

It's in private beta right now like every other new site because we want to have time to set up the site, make sure everything is working right, etc. before the public launch.

[Rory's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146104/146719) does a good job explaining why it didn't go through the normal Area 51 process and gets a special design, but for the most part the site will work like any other SE site and join the network publicly in a couple weeks.

In the meantime, if you're interested in the US Patent system feel free to hop in.  Because it skipped Area 51, anyone is welcome to join the private beta.

Comment: Doesn't private Beta mean only selected users can participate?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: go ahead and make an account. nothing's going to stop you.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Usually, yes, but in this case anyone can join and "private" just means we're not announcing it yet.

Comment: Thanks David! When announced and not in beta anymore, will it appear in the footer alongside the other sites? @mindcorrosive already done that and got 101 shiny points in there! :)

Comment: In case you missed it, [people are wondering about moderation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237827/whats-wrong-with-ask-patents-moderation), and rightfully so IMO. (not a huge deal, but still...)

Answer (score 53):

Reading the [faq](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#askpatents) will make it clear why this one is a wee bit different

> Ask Patents was designed in collaboration with the United States Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO) and Peer To Patent, whose efforts empowering citizens to help find prior art inspired the crowdsourced approach you see here. We also worked with Google to leverage the power of Google Patents Search and their new Prior Art Finder Tool.

So the development was different, and the approach to release has been a bit more low-key.

Comment: Indeed, I just got to that bit. So it's kind of special, it seems.