# Canonical definitions of the Stack Exchange jargon terms "private beta" and "public beta"

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, private-beta, terminology, glossary

In answering [a question on the new patents beta site](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/why-cant-i-see-patents-se-in-the-homepage-of-stackexchange) I wanted to tell the OP about the concepts of "Private Beta" and "Public Beta" here on Stack Exchange.

But I can't seem to find canonical / official definitions, explanations, etc.

There is a thread ["Stack Exchange Glossary"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) but:

- It doesn't contain entries for either "Private Beta" or "Public Beta"
- I can't see any way to **request** an entry for a new term

It seems I can edit the glossary because it's a community wiki, but I don't have the canonical definitions to edit into it and I don't know how to ask whoever does to put them in.

Comment: Perhaps the [area51 faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: @Lix: You would think so. The FAQ only uses the word "private" once and not in this context. Somebody pointed out that the patents.SE is not in area51 either which could be why the OP might not have seen that FAQ. I'll point them to it now though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Private Beta** - only available to those users who committed to the Area 51 proposal *or* have been invited by an existing member.

- Has a plain graphical design that is shared by other sites.
- You can earn privileges with far less reputation than normal.
- Normally lasts 7 days, or until the site is "gelled" enough and has enough high quality content on the home page to consider showing the public.

**Public Beta** - available to the whole internet.

- Has a plain graphical design that is shared by other sites.
- Privileges are earned at higher reputation levels.
- Lasts *at least* 90 days, though often last a lot longer, until the Stack Exchange community team determines that it is likely to be self-sustaining in the long run.

**Graduated Site** - available to the whole internet.

- Has its own graphical design, logo, etc.
- Rarely, requires registration to post questions.
- Privileges are the highest reputation levels.
- Rarely, also has a top level domain (see Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and <strike>Gaming</strike> Arqade.

Comment: Will this do you?

Comment: It looks good to me, but I might not be expert enough of the intricacies of the beta process to say for 100% sure. Should we also seek input from SE staff or should we just stick it in the glossary now? You're much more experienced on SE than myself so I trust your decisions (-:

Comment: And why does _patent.se_ has a special theme even it is in private beta?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka - because it's [special](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146104/59303)

Comment: LOL again redirecting to the old question :)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka - the answer is there, quoted from the site itself

Comment: Yup got it. Thank You

Comment: Merged into the official glossary [with only minor adjustments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/40354/113) - thanks everybody.