# What's the action when a site has no moderation activity?

Tags: support, moderation

On the site I am referring to there are three moderators, one has not been active for more than a month, another announced that he/she is leaving his/her position, and the third, I think, shows no activity.

Comment: Are there any problems happening on the site as a result of this? If possible, see if the resigning moderator would ask for an election.

Comment: No election call by the moment

Comment: Per animuson's answer to [How can a site without moderators start the process to get elected and/or appointed moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348357/how-can-a-site-without-moderators-start-the-process-to-get-elected-and-or-appoin): *If a site has no moderators, whether they've all resigned or they're just not doing anything, we are perfectly aware of that situation and have it noted to do something about it. There is no situation where a site would just slip through the cracks and run indefinitely with no moderation.*

Answer (score 6):

Raise the issue in a Meta post on that site, and if that doesn't work, contact CMs via the site's contact form.

Comment: This of course requires a concerned user to notice and raise the issue. I wonder what happens when nobody does. Truly inactive moderators will be removed after 6 months, and there's a warning a few months before that happens, but I wonder if anything would be done before that, since even a month without active mods can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: The trigger for my question was several unanswered flags, but my biggest concern is the lack of motivation that this generates in the rest of the users.

Comment: @Laurel "*Truly inactive moderators will be removed after 6 months*", unless they marked themselves as inactive? Do you know, perchance?

Comment: @Joachim I've never heard of the tool being used for longer than a few months, so I'm not sure. However, the reason they remove inactive mods is so that they're not a security risk, which marking yourself as inactive doesn't affect.